# add page title as body class via jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass

How can I convert the text within an h1 into a hyphenated string and make it a new class on the body? Here's all I have so far:

```
var newClass = $('h1').val().replace(/ /g, '-');
$("body").addClass(newClass);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kbnt/)

Comment: Seems what you have done is correct except use .text. But question is do you have a class with same name? Do you want to insert class dynamically to the dom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `h1` element you should use `text` instead of `val`, `val` is used for getting/setting values of form elements:

```
var newClass = $('h1').text().replace(/\s/g, '-');
$("body").addClass(newClass);
```

Comment: You're only replacing the first space (in case there is more ?). Otherwise, +1, again!

Comment: cool. will that make capital letters lowercase too? (I can't read regex)

Comment: @nathanbweb No, you can use `toLowerCase` function: `$('h1').text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-');`

Comment: cool. one last thing: omit the last hyphen on the last word? http://jsfiddle.net/7kbnt/3/

Comment: ok. (and I see it was a function of a needless space at the end of the original text anyway). thanks for all your help!